# SharePoint 2013 App Store Issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I am facing difficulty in configuring APP Store in SharePoint 2013.

> Sorry, we can’t seem to connect to the SharePoint Store”. Try again in
>   a bit.

In log there are different errors coming.

> Request to office.com with the following
>   URL: https://office.microsoft.com/config15 caused an exception.
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403)
>   Forbidden. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Marketplace.OfficeProxy.OfficeProxy.SendWebRequest(String
>   url, Boolean autoRedirect, String userIP, String postBody, String
>   contentType, Encoding encoding, String jobRunIdLogPrefix)
>
> Sending Request to Office.com with the following
>   URL:?lc=en%2DUS&type=3&build=15%2E0%2E4569%2E1000&av=OSU150&origin=EC101785291&corr=%7Bc711449d%2D7db3%2D7090%2D1717%2D530cd2b5ca11%7D
>
> Request to office.com with the following
>   URL:?lc=en%2DUS&type=3&build=15%2E0%2E4569%2E1000&av=OSU150&origin=EC101785291&corr=%7Bc711449d%2D7db3%2D7090%2D1717%2D530cd2b5ca11%7D&clientip=10.101.19.55
>   caused a URL exception. Maybe marketplace settings are not setup.
>   Exception details: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format
>   of the URI could not be determined.
>
> at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind
>   uriKind)
>
> at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(String requestUriString)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Marketplace.OfficeProxy.OfficeProxy.SendWebRequest(String
>   url, Boolean autoRedirect, String userIP, String postBody, String
>   contentType, Encoding encoding, String jobRunIdLogPrefix)
>
> Response from office.com was null or its HTTP status code was not
>   'OK'. Actual status code: 'InternalServerError'

SharePoint farm have 4 Apps server, 2 web front end servers.

Can anyone guide me how to configure with in a right way ?

Comment: Do you need to configure a proxy to get internet access? Apps and proxy are a fair bit of pain.

Comment: Yeah.. need proxy to access internet.

Comment: I highly recommend you to bypass the proxy for your SharePoint environment. Priorize that over configuring your SharePoint to support apps via proxy. If you absolutely cannot bypass your proxy, please let me know. I will give you some infos about configuration. BUT: Do not expect that to work perfect or smooth.

Comment: By bypassing the proxy i am able to connect to the app store finally :) Thanks for your help (y)

Comment: @MHeld It was working fine by bypassing. but client reinstall the enthronement again now it is not working again. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue this morning and was able to solve this by adding the SharePoint RootAuthority Certificate to the Trusted Root Certificates in Windows and also to Manage Trusts in SharePoint.

Here's an explanation how to do this: http://sharepoint-sezai-moss-2007.blogspot.de/2012/12/sharepoint-server-2013-rtm-apps-sorry.html

Comment: Already have this entry. Still no luck :(